# SonarQube download specific version

Tags: download, sonarqube

How can I download an older (specific) version of Sonar?  http://www.sonarqube.org/downloads/ only gives certain download options.

Comment: Try from here https://binaries.sonarsource.com/Distribution/sonarqube/

Comment: Not working link...

Answer (score 5):

Go to https://www.sonarqube.org/downloads/ link and under Website Find

```
 Historical Downloads
```

View in Screenshot [image]
All versions listed, Download any version directly..

Answer (score 4):

If you click on the (small) "Show all releases" link at the bottom [here](https://www.sonarqube.org/downloads/), you'll see all the existing versions of SonarQube since version 1.0.2.

Comment: I could not find "Show All releases" option in SonarQube

Answer (score 2):

You can Download from also find older versions

https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/releases/tag/

Answer (score 1):

**[Here](https://sonarsource.bintray.com/Distribution/sonarqube/)** you can find and download specific versions of SonarQube.

Given link https://sonarsource.bintray.com/Distribution/sonarqube/ not working.getting error "Repository path missing or not specified."

Answer (score 1):

SonarQube old releases are maintained on [Github release page](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/releases). One can download it from there

Unable to find it on [SonarQube Official Website](https://www.sonarqube.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link to download all the distribution of Sonarqube.

https://binaries.sonarsource.com/?prefix=Distribution/sonarqube/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33563042)